# работа с циклами python, что я сделал неправильно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Дана последовательность целых положительных чисел. Определить
количество простых чисел в последовательности.

```py
N = [6, 4, 3, 20, 1, 30]
Pr = True

for i in range (0, len(N)):
    for s in range (2, N[i]):
        if N[i]%s == 0:
            Pr = False
            if Pr == True:
                print('Число', N[i], 'Простое')
            else:
                print('Число', N[i], 'Непростое')
```

Comment: Вы выставляете переменную pr = false а затем сразу сравниваете равно ли оно true

Answer (score 0):

Код может выглядеть вот так:

```py
N = [6, 4, 3, 20, 1, 30]

for i in range (0, len(N)):
    Pr = True
    for s in range (2, N[i]):
        if N[i]%s == 0:
            Pr = False
    if Pr:
        print('Число', N[i], 'Простое')
    else:
        print('Число', N[i], 'Непростое')
```

В вашем коде основная ошибка: после того как переменная `Pr` получает значение `False`, больше никогда не изменится.

Результат работы кода:

```py
Число 6 Непростое
Число 4 Непростое
Число 3 Простое
Число 20 Непростое
Число 1 Простое
Число 30 Непростое
```

И с той же логикой можно записать короче. Поскольку `if`ы простые их можно записать в одну строку:

```py
N = [6, 4, 3, 20, 1, 30]

for i in range (0, len(N)):
    Pr = True
    for s in range (2, N[i]):
        if N[i]%s == 0: Pr = False 
    res = 'простое' if Pr else 'не простое'
    print(f"Число {N[i]} {res}")
```

Comment: достаточно проверять до корня числа, или с помощью малой теоремы ферма

Comment: я понимаю, что ТС в начале пути. Путь от простого к сложному. Зачем ему то, что вы указываете? Если на данном этапе он разбирается с простейшим и допускает ошибки. Чтобы он совсем отказался от изучения, поняв, что это какая то сложная дичь? Можете реализовать здесь ответом для будущих поколений

Comment: ну вы можете подправить, просто написав sqrt(N[i]) и все

Comment: Оформите ответом и заодно опишите математические пояснения. Я тоже с удовольствием почитаю, почему и как это работает. А если вы лезете глубже, заодно оцените сложность алгоритма. Мне будет очень полезно